# Правописание н и нн

Tags: орфография

*Она все пела и говорила, что ей очень хорошо, и книги, которые мы брали в библиотеке, я уносил обратно не читанными, так как она уже не могла читать...*

У Чехова в рассказе. Это же ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

> У Чехова в рассказе. Это же ошибка?

Нет, это не ошибка. Чехов очень точен в выборе варианта.
На самом деле тут два вопроса.
1. Допускают ли современные орфографические нормы такое написание?
и 
2. Как на самом деле написано у Чехова?

На первый вопрос ответ очевиден. Никто не запрещает считать это слово причастием, если того хочет автор. И тому есть вполне осмысленное объяснение. ***Нечитаная книга*** - книга которую никто не читал (прилагательное, признак качества). ***Не читанная (мною) книга*** - книга, которая не была читана кем-то конкретным (признак состояния, причастие).

По поводу чеховского варианта. У меня нет академического издания под рукой, но вполне заслуживающие уважения источники дают именно такое написание. 
https://lib-rus.do.am/publ/chekhov_anton_pavlovich_rasskazy_i_povesti_1894_1897_gg_stranica_13/1-1-0-6380
Право слово, это стоит всех ссылок из гуглопомойки.

Так что я более чем допускаю, что Чехов вполне сознательно проводил в жизнь мысль, о которой я сказал выше. Это причастие. Имелось в виду, что книги ***мною*** не читанные. По смыслу это вполне очевидно. Но "мною" тут опущено.

Современные редакторы и корректоры этот момент просто не уловили, оказавшись в плену у "школьной" формулировки, придуманной для того, чтобы отбить охоту к пониманию...

А ведь если разобраться, смысл разделения двух очень прохожих частей речи на причастия и отглагольные прилагательные как раз в том, чтобы передавать подобные нюансы. А не для того, чтобы морочить голову школьникам запоминанием отличий в написании.

Правда, тут еще надо уточнить, когда именно появилось это правило о зависимых словах... Но, сдается мне, при Чехове оно уже существовало. Так что Чехов вряд ли мог случайно сделать аж две ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала несколько слов **об изданиях и  о тексте** самого рассказа (чтобы была понятна ситуация).

*Итак, судьба моя решена, – сказала **сестра**, когда мы пришли домой. – После того, что случилось, я уже не могу возвратиться **туда** …*

*И вот мы начали жить вместе. Она всё пела и говорила, что ей очень хорошо, и книги, которые мы брали в библиотеке, **я уносил обратно не читанными,** так как она уже не могла читать; ей хотелось только мечтать и говорить о будущем…... Она уже **страстно любила своего маленького;** его еще не было на свете, но она уже знала, какие у него глаза, какие руки и как он смеется.*

Это **Полное собрание сочинений в тридцати томах. 
Москва, Наука, 1977 год.**

Полное собрание сочинений и писем Антона Павловича Чехова в тридцати томах – **первое научное издание** литературного наследия великого русского писателя. Оно ставит перед собой задачу дать с исчерпывающей полнотой всё, созданное Чеховым. Рассказы и повести, вошедшие в девятый том, написаны в 1894 («Три года») и 1895–1897 годах.

**Издание 1896 года**

*И вот мы начали жить вместе. Она всё пела и говорила, что ей очень хорошо, и книги, которые мы брали в библиотеке, я уносил обратно **не читанными..***. [А. П. Чехов. Моя жизнь (1896)]

**А теперь о самом вопросе.**

**Это интересный вопрос и очень поучительная история  о том, как мы правим наше правописание и нашу классическую литературу.**

Я задала этот вопрос знакомому **редактору**, но он только плечами пожал: прилагательное, образовано от бесприставочного глагола несовершенного вида, зависимых слов нет. Конечно же, пишется ***нечитаный***.

Этот же вопрос задаст ученик своему учителю с понятным подтекстом: вот даже Чехов с ошибками писал, что же вы от нас хотите? Возможно, учитель поправит его: это **старая орфография,** а по новым правилам надо писать ***уносил нечитаными.***

**Я понимаю наших современников.** Редактору не до тонкостей, ему бы *читаемый* журнал вовремя сдать. В школе свои проблемы: нужно хотя бы какие-то правила освоить и экзамены успешно сдать, не их это дело.

**А тогда чье это дело?** Кто несет полную ответственность за то, что наше правописание перестает выражать смысловые оттенки речи и сводится к формализму? Почему другие народы берегут свою духовность, свои традиции, а мы их безжалостно разрушаем?

**Но это вопросы риторические, а суть дела такова.**

Интересно проследить, как слову ***читаный*** присвоили статус прилагательного (незаконный, надо сказать).

Мы различаем на письме **причастия**, обозначающие глагольный признак, и **прилагательные** с качественным значением. В Правилах 1956 года форма ***читаный*** не упоминается, но есть причастие ***читанный***: доклады, читанные на торжественном заседании. Как мы видим, **зависимое слово** присутствует, хотя этот факт и не подчеркивается.

Розенталь говорит о том, что подобные глагольные формы **переходят в причастия при наличии зависимых слов** (правда, почему – это не известно никому). Но Розенталь относит слово ***читанный*** к причастиям: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62

5. Два н (нн) пишется в бесприставочных причастиях, образованных от глаголов совершенного вида: брошенный, данный, купленный, лишённый, пленённый и др., а также в немногих **причастиях**, образованных от глаголов несовершенного вида: ***виданный, виденный, слыханный, читанный*** и др.

И вот что он еще говорит: "Разграничение страдательных причастий и образованных от них прилагательных (тем самым выбор написания нн или н) иногда производится **не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому значению".** Речь идет о том, что и при отсутствии приставки и пояснительных слов глагольная форма может являться  причастием.

Действительно,  ***видеть, слышать, читать*** – это всего лишь восприятие информации. Так какое же  **качество** может *появиться* в книге, когда ее кто-нибудь прочитает, **синоним у этого качества есть?**

Нет, подобрать синоним сложно: если книгу прочитать аккуратно, никто и не заметит. Например, *стираное белье* – это чистое белье,  *ношеные вещи* –  это вещи потертые и  неновые, а *читаная* книга чем отличается от новой (нечитаной) книги?

Так каким же образом причастие  ***читанный*** выделилось из *информационного* ряда *виденный, виданный, слыханный* и пробралось в прилагательные?

**Версия** такая: помогла форма ***читаный-перечитаный***.  Эти сложные прилагательные обязаны писаться с одним Н, а  у читаной-перечитаной книги **качественный признак явно присутствует** (она-то уж точно новой не выглядит).

Итак, ***читанный – читаный-перчитаный – читаный***, и  вот уже в словарях появляется вполне себе законное прилагательное ***читаный***.

В словаре Ефремовой записано:  ***нечитаный*** прил.Такой, который не читали или не начинали читать. **И где же здесь качественный признак**, почему он определяется через действие?

И вот **результат:** времени прошло не так много,  а редакторы уверены, что всё так и было изначально, а ученики могут считать, что Чехов писал с ошибками.

Что-либо изменить здесь невозможно: по правилам современной орфографии, книги возвращались в библиотеку ***нечитаными***.

Answer (score 1):

Это ошибка, конечно же. Вам не повезло с изданием.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В рассказе прилагательное *[нечитаный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)*.

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: Это ошибка, конечно же._ === Ну почему же ошибка-то? По-моему, допустимы оба варианта.

Comment: @slava1947 - ,более того, вариант с причастием предпочтителен по смыслу.

Comment: @slava1947 От глаголов несовершенного вида образуются и причастия и прилагательные. Пока слово не обросло 1) приставкой, 2) зависимыми словами - это прилагательное. Как только - так сразу.

Answer (score 1):

*Она все пела и говорила, что ей очень хорошо, и **книги**, которые мы брали в библиотеке, **я уносил обратно не читанными, так как она уже не могла читать**; ей хотелось только мечтать и говорить о будущем* ([А. П. Чехов. Моя жизнь](http://rulibrary.ru/chekhov/moya_zhizn/45)).

Если бы мне пришлось выбирать (прилагательное *нечитаными* или причастие *не читанными*), я бы выбрала все-таки причастие.

...*книги я уносил обратно не читанными* (кем?) [ею]…
Здесь, думаю, пропущено зависимое местоимение **ею** (но оно подразумевается), потому что в следующей части предложения говорится, что **именно она** книги не читала (*так как она уже не могла читать*).
Смысл предложения таков: **МЫ** брали книги, чтобы читать (а для чего же ещё берут книги в библиотеке?); книги же  возвращались прочитанными мною, но не читанными ею (автор читал, а она — нет).
Поэтому, как мне кажется, нельзя сказать *нечитаными*, так как один из героев их все-таки прочитал ("процесс чтения" все-таки был).

[НЕ с причастиями, слитно или раздельно](http://reshit.ru/ne-s-prichastiyami-slitno-i-razdel%27no-primery)